# How to eager load binary fields without changing ".designer.cs" file in LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, eager-loading

By default LinqToSql generated classes wrap `varbinary(max)` fields in the form of `Link<>` which means they are loaded on demand. One way to change this is to alter the class schema in LinqToSql visual editor. However this way is not a desired one since all manual changes may be easily lost if we later forget about them and re-generate the classes.

The question is how to eager load binary fields without changing LinqToSql classes in visual editor, sort of using `DataLoadOptions.LoadWith()` maybe?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use LoadWith? Using options.LoadWith<ModelClass>(x => x.BinaryField) works fine for me.

Comment: I once had a similar problem regarding a requirement to not lose manual changes made in the dbml. I ended up writing NUnit tests that inspected the properties of the dbml (using reflection) so that any breaking changes would be noticed in the build.